# Getting span contents with “Simple HTML DOM”

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape Twitter tweets from a user page using “Simple HTML DOM”.

I can get the tweets but not their timestamp.

The HTML seems to be like this:

```
<p class="ProfileTweet-text js-tweet-text u-dir" lang="en" dir="ltr" data-aria-label-part="0">Tweet content<a href="/hashtag/TweetContent?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" ><s>#</s><b>TweetContent</b></a> <a href="http://t.co/JFredfvgYs" class="twitter-timeline-link u-hidden" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >pic.twitter.com/JFredfvgYs</a></p>
```

The UNIX timestamp is in this:

```
<span class="js-short-timestamp "
    data-aria-label-part="last"
    data-time="1411584273"
    data-long-form="true" >
    Sep 24
  </span>
```

So I'm doing:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://twitter.com/UserName');
$tweets = $html->find('div.ProfileTweet-contents');
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
$tweetText = $tweet->find('p.ProfileTweet-text', 0)->plaintext;
echo $tweetText;
}
?>
```

... which is fine for getting the tweet text but I don't know how to approach getting that Unix timestamp.

I thought maybe:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://twitter.com/UserName');
$tweets = $html->find('div.ProfileTweet-contents');
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
$tweetText = $tweet->find('p.ProfileTweet-text', 0)->plaintext;
$tweetDate = $tweet->find('span.js-short-timestamp ', 0);
echo $tweetText.' '.$tweetDate->data-time;
?>
```

... but that's all wrong.  Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely because of that property that you're trying to access. Wrapped that hypenated property with this:

```
$tweetDate->{'data-time'};
```

Rough example:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://twitter.com/katyperry');
$tweet_block = $html->find('div.ProfileTweet');
foreach($tweet_block as $tweet) {
    // get tweet text
    $tweetText = $tweet->find('p.ProfileTweet-text text', 0)->innertext;
    echo 'Tweet: ' . $tweetText . '<br/>';

    // get tweet stamp
    $tweetDate = $tweet->find('a.ProfileTweet-timestamp span.js-short-timestamp', 0);
    echo 'Timestamp: ' .$tweetDate->{'data-time'} . '<br/>';

    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: Yep! (roughly)  Wrapping the hyphenated property works!  Many thanks sir !